# Pick up random number with predefined chance

Tags: calculus

I got a small group of numbers $0,1,2,3...n$. I want to randomly select one of those numbers, how ever I want to make it that the higher numbers will have less chance to be picked up.

I want to make it that the chance of picking the $k | 0 > k > n$ number will be greater by multiplication of $x$ from picking $k -1$ number.

The only tool that I got for this task is random method that will return a random number between $0$ to $1$.

I am doing this for a game that I develope, how do I solve this?

Comment: Check out the [inversion method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), it's a very simple and general way of solving this problem so you get a random variable for the distribution of your choosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be the probability of picking 0. Then the probability of picking 1 is $px$, the probability of picking 2 is $px^2$, and for any $k, 0 \le k \le n$ the probability of picking $k$ is $px^k$. These probabilities must total to 1.

Now,

$$\sum_{k=0}^n px^k = \frac{p(1 - x^{n+1})}{1 - x}\, , x \ne 1$$

Thus $1 = \frac{p(1 - x^{n+1})}{1 - x}$
i.e., $p = \frac{1 - x}{(1 - x^{n+1})}$
finding $x$ in terms of $p$ is messy...

To choose a number with the required probability using a standard random number generator that returns a value $v : 0 \le v \lt 1$, we first generate $v$.

If $v < p$ we pick 0.
Else if $v < p + px$ we pick 1.
Else if $v < p + px + px^2$ we pick 2. Etc.
But rather than having a huge chain of else if statements in the program we can utilize that sum formula above. We have to re-arrange it to give us $n$ in terms of the other variables.

Let

$$\begin{align}
v = & \frac{p(1 - x^{n+1})}{1 - x}\\
v(1-x)/p = & 1 - x^{n+1}\\
x^{n+1} = & 1 - v(1-x)/p\\
\log(x^{n+1}) = & \log(1 - v(1-x)/p)\\
(n+1)\log x = & \log(1 - v(1-x)/p)\\
n + 1 = & \log(1 - v(1-x)/p) / \log x\\
\end{align}$$

In general, the $n+1$ we get from this will not be an integer, but if we round it down to the nearest integer it will give us the number we need to pick. I.e., if $k \le \log(1 - v(1-x)/p) / \log x \lt k + 1$, then we pick $k$.

Here's some Python 2 code that illustrates this method.

```
from math import log

n = 10
x = 1.1
p = (1 - x) / (1 - x**n)

def invert(s, p, x):
    y = log(1 - s*(1 - x)/p) / log(x)
    return int(y)

s = v = p
for i in range(10):
    print '%2d: %s' % (i, s)
    v *= x
    s += v

print 10*'-'

for i in range(10):
    s = 0.1 * i
    j = invert(s, p, x)
    print '%2d: %s %s' % (i, s, j)

print 10*'-'

print invert(0, p, x)
print invert(0.99999999, p, x)
print invert(1, p, x)
```

And here's its output

```
 0: 0.0627453948825
 1: 0.131765329253
 2: 0.207687257061
 3: 0.29120137765
 4: 0.383066910297
 5: 0.484118996209
 6: 0.595276290713
 7: 0.717549314667
 8: 0.852049641016
 9: 1.0
----------
 0: 0.0 0
 1: 0.1 1
 2: 0.2 2
 3: 0.3 4
 4: 0.4 5
 5: 0.5 6
 6: 0.6 7
 7: 0.7 7
 8: 0.8 8
 9: 0.9 9
----------
0
9
10
```

**Update** I hate off-by-one errors. :) The above method will pick numbers from 0 to 9 given $n=10$ and a random number generator that returns a value $v : 0 \le v \lt 1$. Hopefully, that's not a major issue for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's set the base chance of picking up $0$ as $b$.

Then the chance of picking up $1$ is $b \cdot x$, where $x < 1$.

Then the chance of picking up $2$ is $b \cdot x^2$.

This continues until we get to the chance of picking up $n$, which is $b \cdot x^n$.

All of these chances must add up to $1$.

(This is how I'm interpreting your problem, anyway; feel free to ignore this if this model is wrong.)

Hence we have

$$1 = \sum_{i = 0}^n b \cdot x^i = b \cdot \sum_{i = 0}^n x^i = b \cdot \sum_{i = 0}^{(n+1)-1} x^i = b \cdot \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}.$$

So, we get that $b = \dfrac{1-x}{1-x^{n+1}}$.

At this point, you get to do some tuning. Choose an $x$ say, get a $b$, try it out in your game to see if it feels appropriate.